# Locking Levels in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I started to script recently and don't really know all that much. I wanted to start a simple level lock system to begin. The locking works and I'm using it with a level saver script but if i played to level 10 and I play level 1 again it locks all other levels except 1 and 2. Can somebody please help? This is the code:

```
[SerializeField] int levelRequirement;
        public void Start()
        {
            int currentLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level");
            bool levelUnlocked = currentLevel >= levelRequirement;
            GetComponent<Button>().interactable = levelUnlocked;

        }
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now!

Comment: From your code the issue seems not reproducible but my guess is: You don't check the Maximum unlocked level but as soon as you finish level1 you simply do `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("level, 1")` and thereby overwrite even if the value is already higher ... you probably want to do `if(1 > currentLevel) { PlayerPrefs.SetInt("level", 1); }` and accordingly for each level

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be in `PlayerPrefs.SetInt()`. Make sure you make a check whether the `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level")` is less (or maybe <=) than the current level so It only saves when the last unlocked level is played. Or you can set the value if the next level number is greater than `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("level")`.